# how to do tab navigation in the screen without using tab navigator in React native mobile

Tags: react-native

[image: Tab naavigation without using Tab navigator]

I want to create screen where i can toggle between All Assets, Hardware .. etc. but the catch all the tabs data should be present in one screen (Assets, hardware..etc are not separate screens) getting a tough time in designing this screen.Need help

I want to do a similar approach as https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-switch-selector but as tabs with the design shown below (I don't want each tab to be redirected to a different screen) Goal is each tab should show different api data.

Comment: try to explain your idea more!

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want to have a tab navigator, but you don't want it to be a tab navigator. Instead, you want it to do something custom, like change state so that your screen just changes its contents, rather than navigate to a different screen. That **is** actually possible!

Use the `tabPress` event and remember to prevent the default behavior by using event.preventDefault. Docs are [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator#tabpress).